# Issue with requests from Nuxt.js not adding cookies to Django server

Tags: django, vue.js, cookies

I'm working with a Nuxt.js frontend and a Django backend and encountering an issue where cookies are not being set correctly after JWT authentication. My Nuxt.js app is running on `https://localhost:3000` and the Django server is on `https://localhost:8000`.

Despite successful authentication using JWT tokens, when I make a request to the server, the cookies are not being attached. Checking the Network tab, I noticed that the client-side isn't sending cookies.

[image]

[image]
Here's my Django settings related to CORS and cookies:

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://localhost:3000",
]

# Other settings...

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

And this is how I'm making the request in Nuxt.js:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>User Profile</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="getUserInfo">
            <button type="submit">UserInfo</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    methods: {
        async getUserInfo() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:8000/api/userinfo/', {
                }, {
                    withCredentials: true
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I suspect the issue might be related to CORS or cookie settings, but I'm not sure what's missing or incorrect in my configuration. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Following up on the details provided, I've verified that the `withCredentials: true` setting is being used in the Axios request, which should include cookies in the request to the server. However, the cookies still seem to be missing in the server-side requests.

A few points that I think might be relevant to this issue:

1. **SameSite Attribute of Cookies**: I've set `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'` in Django, which should allow cross-origin use of cookies. Is this the correct setup for a Vue.
2. **Secure Flags on Cookies**: Since both applications are running in a development environment with `https`, I've set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True`.
3. **CORS Configuration**: I have `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` in my Django settings and I've specified the Vue.js origin in `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`.
4. **Browser Behavior**: Could this issue be related to specific browser settings regarding cookies and security, especially since I'm working in a development environment with self-signed SSL certificates?
5. **Django Session Management**: Is there something specific in Django's session management that I should look into to ensure that cookies are set and sent correctly?

Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding if there's a common pitfall or configuration oversight in such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

Changed axios to fetch. And added the `credentials:'include'` parameter.
I confirmed that cookies were added. I don't know how to do something similar using axios. If anyone knows, please let me know in the comments.

```
<script>    
export default {
    methods: {
        async getUserInfo() {
            fetch('https://localhost:8000/api/userinfo/', {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include' // This is the correct setting for Fetch API to include credentials
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

[image]

```
 const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:8000/api/userinfo/', {
                }, {
                    withCredentials: true
                });
```

I also confirmed that cookies are delayed on axios. I don't understand why cookies couldn't be sent in the first place...

I think it may be necessary to restart nuxt after changing the settings.